# Property of subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the following property correct?

**Property:**  let $(G;f_G)$ group, $B \subseteq G$ and $B \neq \emptyset $, then $(B;f_G|_B)$ is group iff $\forall a,b \in B$ we have that $a f_G|_B b'\in B $ and $ b $ is symmetry element  of $b'$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I haven't seen this notation before, what does $f_G$ represent?

Comment: @muzzlator, $f_G$ is binary operation $f_G:G^2 \rightarrow G $, and $f_G|B$ is the restriction function in $B$..

Comment: Oh, I see.  Then yes, it is correct.  To check $B$ is a subgroup, you need only check $ab^{-1} \in B$ given $a,b \in B$.  This is the more common notation.  See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sufficiency_of_subgroup_criterion

Comment: @muzzlator your notation is additive.. is true?

Comment: Then don't you mean $(B;f_G|_B)$ is a group, not $(G;f_G|_B)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews... true, sorry..typo!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok, thanks!!

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc Ignore my previous comment - I didn't realize you were the poster of the question, so I thought you were asking about the quesiton. muzzlator's notation is multiplicative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews.. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: is correct to write $\forall a,b \in B, \exists b' \in B : a f_G|_B b'\in B $...

Comment: @muzzlator, but $b' \in B$???

Comment: That is implied.  $b b' \in B$ shows that $1 \in B$.  $1 b' \in B$ shows $b' \in B$.  So ultimately all you need to do is show that $a, b \in B \implies ab' \in B$ and that $B$ is non-empty of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is true.  To show that a subset of a group is a subgroup, the subset must contain the identity, must contain the inverse of each of its elements, and must be closed under the group operation.

$B$ contains the identity because $bf_G|_Bb' \in B$.  Write $e$ for the identity element.

The product $ef_G|_Bb'$ lies in $B$ for any $b \in B$, so $B$ contains the inverses of each of its elements.

Finally, to show closure, write $(b')' = b$.  Then $af_G|_B(b')' = af_G|_Bb \in B$

(I'm unfamiliar with your notation and vocabulary.  I'm answering as if $f_G$ means the group operation, $af_Gb$ means "the product of $a$ and $b$," and "symmetry element" means "inverse."  Most users of this site would say "If $B \subset G$ and $ab^{-1} \in B$ for all $a, b \in B$, then $B$ is a subgroup of $G$.)

**Edit**: As egreg and Thomas Anderson point out, the first step relies on the assumption that $B$ is non-empty.  Were $B$ empty, there would be no $b$ to use in the product $bf_G|_Bb'$.

Comment: The fact that $B\ne\emptyset$ is crucial and you're not mentioning it.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary for the first step - that step relies on some $b\in B$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to prove it in steps. First show that, since $B$ is not empty, we can use the condition to show that $1_G\in B$.

Then use that to show that if $b\in B$ then $b'\in B$.

Then use that to show that if $a,b\in B$ then $af_G|_Bb\in B$.

Comment: ok, but is correct to write $\forall a,b \in B, \exists b' \in B : a f_G|_B b'\in B $...